# Make updatedb ignore dot-paths

Tags: search

Anyone know how to make updatedb ignore 'hidden' paths? This isn't any kind of security issue; I just want updates to be faster. I've tried using the -n and -e flags with '.*' to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define directories that should be omitted in `/etc/updatedb.conf`. You can use regular expressions, citing [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Invoking-updatedb.html):

> --prunepaths='path...'
>   Directories to omit from the database, which would otherwise be
>   included. The environment variable
>   PRUNEPATHS also sets this value.
>   Default is /tmp /usr/tmp /var/tmp
>   /afs. The paths are used as regular
>   expressions (with find ... -regex, so
>   you need to specify these paths in the
>   same way that find will encounter
>   them. This means for example that the
>   paths must not include trailing
>   slashes.

So change the following line in `/etc/updatedb.conf`:

```
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media"
```

to:

```
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media .*/\..*"
```

should work just fine ;-)